# How can I refactor repetitive switch statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring

I have the following switch statement.
But there are repeated codes here and I want to get rid of this.
please refactor this code.

```
var something;
switch(alphabet) {
  case "A":
     something.aa = true;
     something.bb = false;
     something.cc = false;
     break;
  case "B":
     something.aa = false;
     something.bb = true;
     something.cc = false;
     break;
  case "C":
     something.aa = false;
     something.bb = false;
     something.cc = true;
     break;
}
```

Comment: set everything to "false" before the switch, then you only need to set one of the variables to "true" in each case

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be the better place for this question. `var something = { aa: alphabet === 'A' /*...*/ }` might be a way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about leaving the switch statement completely out?

```
var something = {
  aa: alphabet === "A",
  bb: alphabet === "B",
  cc: alphabet === "C"
}
```

Comment: I liked this way. +1

Comment: Oh, I like this answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to use an array of the keys and a loop that compares  that letter to the key with whatever logic is applicable. In your example it would be a simple `includes()` or `startsWith()`

Something like:

```
const keys = ['aa','bb', 'cc'];
const lower = alphabet.toLowerCase();
keys.forEach(k => something[k] = k.includes(lower))
```

Comment: I never thought about this approach. Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

So, at any point in time, only one case will be true, right. Keeping that in mind, you can do the following:

```
var something = {aa:false,bb:false,cc:false},
switch(alphabet) {
  case "A":
     something.aa = true;
     break;
  case "B":
     something.bb = true;
     break;
  case "C":
     something.cc = true;
     break;
}
```

Hope that helps. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could take an object wthe targets for `true`, like

```
var targets = {
        A: 'aa',
        B: 'bb',
        C: 'bb',
    },
    something = { aa: false, bb: false, cc: false };

// usage
if (alphabet in targets) something[targets[alphabet]] = true;
```

Comment: `something` has to be rebuilt though whenever that code is executed.